# How do you pronounce Ksyrium?

Tags: wheels

Mavic make a wheelset called Ksyrium.  I can spell it but every time I go to say it, I come out with something different.

Does anybody know how to pronounce the name?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's pronounced without the K, see-ree-um.

Source: a bunch of bike-shop-workers who seemed to know their wheels ;)

Comment: Also first 5 seconds of this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QEDaGiWdhJI (first video result in a google search for Ksyrium)